# Problem installing Slate API Document Generator on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: ruby, api, rubygems, bundler

When installing [Slate API Document Generator](https://github.com/slatedocs/slate) on Ubuntu 18.04, I stumbled upon this error:

```
Can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

How would I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the bundler version of slate:

```
$ cat Gemfile.lock | grep -A 1 "BUNDLED WITH"
BUNDLED WITH
   2.0.2
```

So to fix that I install the same version bundler

```
$ gem install bundler -v '2.0.2'
```

However, other issue appear, the installation stuck because Ruby is unable to compile some dependencies. To fix this, I install the following (not mentioned in the original Slate wiki):

```
sudo apt install zlib1g-dev build-essential ruby-full
```

With that all my issues are solved and I am able to complete the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the exact bundler used in your application with the following command:

`gem install bundler -v "$(grep -A 1 "BUNDLED WITH" Gemfile.lock | tail -n 1)"`